# shoulda, rspec, guard, spork issues with http responses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, shoulda

Hello and thanks for you patience!
My rails app uses a combination of rspec and shoulda to run tests. The tests are automated over guard and spork. One of my controllers tests looks like

> it {should respond_with(:success)}

When running tests i get

> Expected response to be a 200, but was 301

manually testing by browsing & wget things go right, the page is responding correctly with 200 status code. As I am quite new to rails testing, proberly I am not understanding how the tests are currently ran. How are they implemented? What was the purpose of the environment 'test'? Is there some kind of webserver running in backgroud to run the tests? Obviously there is some kind of non-wanted redirecting.
Thanks in advance!

## Edit: More sources

controller:

```
 class PlansController < ApplicationController
   def index
     @plans=Plan.all
   end
    ... more methods ...
 end
```

test:

```
  describe PlansController do
    before :each do
      @plan=FactoryGirl.create(:plan)
    end
    
    context " get :index" do
      before do 
        get :index 
      end

      it {should respond_with(:success)}
    end
    ... more tests..
  end
```

Comment: Don't you have any redirection?

Comment: currently no. _routes.rb_ just declares `resources :plans ` and have an alias like `match '/pricing' => 'plans#index'`. You got that the test i mentioned before was on methods of the PlansController class.

Comment: Well, redirections usually occur within the controller

Comment: Maybe you have some authentication filter before this action and you don't define it on your spec

Comment: editing question to show more code, anyway i don't have any redirection atm in my controller.

Comment: `force_ssl` was on ApplicationController and silently redirecting all requests to https :/

Comment: You should put that in as an answer and then accept it so that this question will be removed from the unanswered lists.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an `:each` in the before block of the context for `get :index` so you are never calling the index action.

Update as follows:

```
context " get :index" do
  before(:each) do 
    get :index 
  end

  it { should respond_with(:success) }
end
```

Comment: `before do` is the same as `before :each do` in rspec.  Just a convenience.